# where does OSs keep the programs that are not used for some minutes?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Typically in a working environment, I have many windows open, Outlook, 2/3 word docuements, few windows in browser, notepad++, some vpn client, excel etc..

Having said that, there are chances that about 40% of these apps are not frequently used, but are referred only sparingly.  They occupy memory none-the-less.

Now, how does a typical OS deal with that kind of memory consumption ?  does it suspend that app to hard disk (pagefile , or linux swap area etc) thereby freeing up that memory for usage, or does it keep occupying the memory there as it is.

Can this suspension be a practical solution, doable thing ? Are there any downsides ? response time ?

Is there some study material I can refer to for reading on this topic/direction..

would appreciate the help here.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but an OS question and as such, off-topic here.

Comment: Any suggestions on the right forum for such a discussion ?

Answer (score 2):

The detailed answer depends on your OS and how it implements its memory management, but here is a generality:

The OS doesnt look at memory in terms of how many processes are in RAM, it looks at in terms of discrete units called pages. Most processes have several pages of RAM. Pages that are least referenced can be swapped out of RAM and onto the hard disk when physical RAM becomes scarce. Rarely, therefore, is an entire process swapped out of RAM, but only certain parts of it. It could be, for example, that some aspect of your currently running program is idle (ie the page is rarely accessed). In that case, it could be swapped out even though the process is in the foreground.

Try [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) for starters on how this process works and the many methods to implement it.